# JQuery finding element by attibute value

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml file and would like to retrieve the contents of the key attribute.

The structure of the xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<MPL Version="2.0" Title="MCWS - Files - 2100">
  <Item>
    <Field Name="Key">1383</Field>
    <Field Name="Name">En la Planta de Tus Pies</Field>
    <Field Name="Artist">Alejandro Sanz</Field>
    <Field Name="Album">El Tren de los Momentos</Field>
    <Field Name="Genre">Latin</Field>
  </item>
<Item>
    <Field Name="Key">938</Field>
    <Field Name="Name">Something Beautiful</Field>
    <Field Name="Artist">Robbie Williams</Field>
    <Field Name="Album">Escapology</Field>
    <Field Name="Genre">Rock</Field>
  </item>
</MPL>
```

My JQuery function looks like this:

```
function displaySongs() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"Files.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
    var content = "";

    $(xml).find('Item').each(function(){
    var songId = $(this).find('Field[Name="Key"]');
    var songName = $(this).find('Field[Name="Name"]');

    content += "<div class=\"Song\">" + songName.text() + "</div>";
    $("#output").html(content);     
    }); 
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
  });
}
```

My problem is that i am not finding the content of the Name="Name" node, but get the entire item result.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a special function for returning attribute values:

`$('Field').attr('Name');`

This should return the value of the attribute.

However, I've never used jQuery on XML, so I'm not sure how it would treat it. Nevertheless, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
   var xml = $.parseXML(outputFromAJAXXML),
   $xml = $( xml ),
   $test = $xml.find('Field[Name="Name"]');
   console.log($test.text()); // This works
```

The above outputs ,  concatenated Names - `En la Planta de Tus Pies` and `Something Beautiful`  as one single String

The below works perfectly. Check the jsFiddle Link here http://jsfiddle.net/k5sVt/15/ :

```
  $(outputFromAJAXXML).find('Field[Name="Name"]').each(function()
  {
   console.log('****'+$(this).text());
  });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but it still shows the entire content of the item. I think i should have explained it a little better. I am trying to iterate through the results of the Item collection and trying to retrieve the value of the node with the name attribute with the value name.